# Generate a Certificate in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having facing issue with the below code
Issue is when i run this file it automatically prints all user in my database
I'm having a hard time on selecting one user and print only that user.

Can anyone here help me?

````
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mylib');//connect sa database
$query="select * from reguser" ;//select column
$fire=mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($fire))
{
   header('content-type:image/jpeg');
   $font= realpath('arial.ttf');
   $image=imagecreatefromjpeg("format.jpg");
   $color=imagecolorallocate($image, 51, 51, 102);
   $date=date('d F, Y');//Current Date 
   imagettftext($image, 18, 0, 880, 188, $color,$font, $date);
   $name=$row['username'];
   imagettftext($image, 48, 0, 120, 520, $color,$font, $name);
   imagejpeg($image,"certificate/$name.jpg");//Storing certificate here
   imagedestroy($image);
}
?>```
````

Comment: The title of your question is very misleading because "generating a certificate" is a very specific thing usually related to ssl certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You are running your certificate printing code inside a loop by executing `Select * from reguser` query and using a while loop.

Instead, if you want to print it only for a single, specific user, then try this:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, select * from reguser where id=5);
```

You can replace the where clause's condition with whatever you feel like if you don't want to get the user with their id.

```
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql); // Get the required user like this:
// certificate printing code
header('content-type:image/jpeg');
$font= realpath('arial.ttf');
$image=imagecreatefromjpeg("format.jpg");
$color=imagecolorallocate($image, 51, 51, 102);
$date=date('d F, Y');//Current Date 
imagettftext($image, 18, 0, 880, 188, $color,$font, $date);
$name=$user['username'];
imagettftext($image, 48, 0, 120, 520, $color,$font, $name);
imagejpeg($image,"certificate/$name.jpg");//Storing certificate here
imagedestroy($image);
```

This should do this trick!

Answer (score 0):

You must specified wich user you want to show in MySQL query with WHERE clause.

> The WHERE clause is used to extract only those records that fulfill a
> specified condition. [more details](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_where.asp)

this will help you:

```
***
$user_id = "replace the user id here";
$query="select * from reguser WHERE id='".$user_id."'" ;//select column
***
```